# Excel - How to get header columns value from pivot table and inject them into a drop-down list

Tags: excel, header, pivot-table, dropdown

I would like to retrieve all values of the header of each column of a pivot table in order to inject that into a drop-down list in another sheet.

Could you tell me please how to retrieve the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by using the function `OFFSET`

For the header of the column:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OFFSET('TABLE PIVOT'!$B$4;;ROW(C1)-1)=0; "";OFFSET('TABLE PIVOT'!$B$4;;ROW(C1)-1));0)
```

For the header of the row:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OFFSET('TABLE PIVOT'!$A$5;ROW(A1)-1;)=0; "";OFFSET('TABLE PIVOT'!$A$5;ROW(A1)-1;));0)
```